# angularjs date Format doesn't work in controller for format yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-format

date format in angularjs doesn't work when I format: `yyyy/MM/dd`

date from datepicker `ng-model="Periode1"` = `01 January 2016`

I tried:

```
var p1 = new Date($scope.Periode1);
$scope.period1Convert = $filter('date')(p1, "yyyy/MM/dd");

output : null
```

and also:

```
var d = new Date($scope.Periode1);
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
curr_month++;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
$scope.period1Convert = (curr_year + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_date);

output : NaN/NaN/NaN
```

Please help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you filter is working fine. Make sure you assign the value to `ng-model` variable before executing the filter.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope, $filter){

$scope.Periode1 = "01 January 2016";
var p1 = new Date($scope.Periode1);
$scope.period1Convert = $filter('date')(p1, "yyyy/MM/dd");
console.log($scope.period1Convert)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried to make a function. and success :)